# Twitter login for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I am using the following library for implementing twitter codeigniter.
https://github.com/vixnet/codeigniter-twitter

I am able to go to the twitter authorize url, where i give the login credentials for twitter,
on accepting it, i am being redirected to my callback url as per the procedure with a GET request with the parameters access_token and access_verifier.

But i am not able to fetch these parameters in the controller which is the callback url.

Can please anybody provide any inputs ?

Comment: Not even using the methods from the [`Input Class`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) or `$_REQUEST` ?

Comment: i am seeing in the network of my browser console, its a GET request. This is the callback url with the GET request, "http://wowdesigns.in/projects/bigpress/index.php/index.php/tweet_test/auth?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". i am not able to capture these parameters using $_GET

Comment: What are you setting as the callback url? There seems to be multiple `index.php` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is messing with your `$_GET`

I am recreating it with: `$_GET = get_get();`

```
function get_get()
{
    $parts = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(!isset($parts[1])) 
    {
        return array();
    }
    $params = explode("&", $parts[1]);
    foreach($params as $par)
    {
        $par = explode("=", $par);
        if(!isset($par[1]))
        {
            $par[1] = '';
        }
        $__GET[$par[0]] = $par[1];
    }
    return $__GET;
}
```